# What's the recommended way to set the output file for MediaRecorder... in Android Q?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

Up to now, I've been storing recorded and edited videos in a custom directory I got from this line of code:

`File mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Constant.CUSTOM_DIRECTORY);`

However, `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is apparently deprecated in Android Q, with the accepted alternatives being `Context.getExternalFilesDir(type : String)`, `MediaStore`, and `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` which I'm not sure of for this particular case.

How do I achieve saving to a custom directory in Android Q, or is that not possible or recommended in Android Q?

Comment: android 10 uses a different way to access the files using something called the storage access framework
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

Comment: @Gensoukyou1337, the same situation here, I tried to save the recorded video with `Context.getExternalFilesDir`, but doesn't work could you please share me your solution, if you could